# Difference between Accumulating windows and Discarding windows in Apache Beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a sample pipeline here:

```
def print_windows(element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,  pane_info=beam.DoFn.PaneInfoParam, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
    print(window)
    print(pane_info)
    print(timestamp)
    print(element)
    print('-----------------')

options = PipelineOptions()
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    keyed_elements = [
        ('USA', {'score': 1, 'timestamp': 2}),
        ('USA', {'score': 2, 'timestamp': 4}),
        ('USA', {'score': 3, 'timestamp': 4}),
        ('USA', {'score': 4, 'timestamp': 5}),
        ('USA', {'score': 5, 'timestamp': 14}),
        ('USA', {'score': 6, 'timestamp': 17}),
    ]

    elements = (
        p 
        | beam.Create(keyed_elements)
        | 'ConvertIntoUserEvents' >> beam.Map(lambda e: beam.window.TimestampedValue(e, e[1]['timestamp']))
        | beam.Map(lambda e: (e[0], e[1]['score']))
    )

    results = (
        elements
        | "" >> beam.WindowInto(
            beam.window.FixedWindows(10),
            trigger=Repeatedly(AfterCount(2)),
            accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING
        )
        | beam.CombinePerKey(beam.combiners.ToListCombineFn())
    )


    results | beam.ParDo(print_windows)
```

The idea is simple- I want to take in some timestamped scores and combine them in a list. I trigger each pane after I see 2 elements.

If I run this as is, I get:

```
[0.0, 10.0)
PaneInfo(first: True, last: False, timing: EARLY, index: 0, nonspeculative_index: -1)
Timestamp(9.999000)
('USA', [1, 2, 3, 4])
-----------------
[10.0, 20.0)
PaneInfo(first: True, last: False, timing: EARLY, index: 0, nonspeculative_index: -1)
Timestamp(19.999000)
('USA', [5, 6])
```

But, if I change the accumulation mode to DISCARDING, the output stays the same. I'm confused because from what I understand at a high level, ACCUMULATING would output panes like:

`[1, 2] ... [1, 2, 3, 4]` for the first 10 second window and then `[5, 6]` for the last 10 second window.

DISCARDING, on the other hand, should give:

`[1, 2] .. [3, 4]` and then `[5,6]`. Why are the outputs the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Beam concepts a Window can contain 0 to N panes which is controlled by the trigger definition in application code.

When a trigger is defined as `Accumulating` it means that any value which is part of a Window and is triggered based on the trigger logic is retained and is appended to the new values as and when new Panes are fired or when a Window is closed.

When a trigger is defined as `Discarding` it means that any value which is part of a Window and is triggered based on the trigger logic is discarded and is not available to the following new Panes that are fired or when a Window is closed.

In the example above if the triggering logic is changed to the below you can observe minimum two Panes:-

1. EARLY
2. ON_TIME

```
beam.transforms.trigger.AfterWatermark(early=AfterCount(2))
```

With `ACCUMULATING` panes below is the behaviour

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.fn_api_runner:Running (CombinePerKey(ToListCombineFn)/GroupByKey/Read)+((CombinePerKey(ToListCombineFn)/Combine)+(ref_AppliedPTransform_ParDo(CallableWrapperDoFn)_26))
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:10:00
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:12:00
INFO:root:PaneInfo(first: True, last: False, timing: EARLY, index: 0, nonspeculative_index: -1)
INFO:root:Timestamp(1590329519.999000)
INFO:root:('USA', [{'score': 1, 'ts': 5}, {'score': 2, 'ts': 5}])
INFO:root:-----------------
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:12:00
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:14:00
INFO:root:PaneInfo(first: True, last: False, timing: EARLY, index: 0, nonspeculative_index: -1)
INFO:root:Timestamp(1590329639.999000)
INFO:root:('USA', [{'score': 5, 'ts': 105}, {'score': 4, 'ts': 60}, {'score': 6, 'ts': 105}, {'score': 3, 'ts': 60}])
INFO:root:-----------------
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:10:00
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:12:00
INFO:root:PaneInfo(first: False, last: True, timing: ON_TIME, index: 1, nonspeculative_index: 0)
INFO:root:Timestamp(1590329519.999000)
INFO:root:('USA', [{'score': 1, 'ts': 5}, {'score': 2, 'ts': 5}])
INFO:root:-----------------
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:12:00
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:14:00
INFO:root:PaneInfo(first: False, last: True, timing: ON_TIME, index: 1, nonspeculative_index: 0)
INFO:root:Timestamp(1590329639.999000)
INFO:root:('USA', [{'score': 5, 'ts': 105}, {'score': 4, 'ts': 60}, {'score': 6, 'ts': 105}, {'score': 3, 'ts': 60}])
INFO:root:-----------------
```

With `DISCARDING` pane below is the behavior

```
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:12:00
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:14:00
INFO:root:PaneInfo(first: True, last: False, timing: EARLY, index: 0, nonspeculative_index: -1)
INFO:root:Timestamp(1590329639.999000)
INFO:root:('USA', [{'score': 2, 'ts': 5}, {'score': 4, 'ts': 60}, {'score': 1, 'ts': 5}, {'score': 3, 'ts': 60}])
INFO:root:-----------------
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:14:00
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:16:00
INFO:root:PaneInfo(first: True, last: False, timing: EARLY, index: 0, nonspeculative_index: -1)
INFO:root:Timestamp(1590329759.999000)
INFO:root:('USA', [{'score': 5, 'ts': 105}, {'score': 6, 'ts': 105}])
INFO:root:-----------------
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:12:00
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:14:00
INFO:root:PaneInfo(first: False, last: True, timing: ON_TIME, index: 1, nonspeculative_index: 0)
INFO:root:Timestamp(1590329639.999000)
INFO:root:('USA', [])
INFO:root:-----------------
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:14:00
INFO:root:2020-05-24 14:16:00
INFO:root:PaneInfo(first: False, last: True, timing: ON_TIME, index: 1, nonspeculative_index: 0)
INFO:root:Timestamp(1590329759.999000)
INFO:root:('USA', [])
INFO:root:-----------------
```

In the case of `ACCUMULATING` the values from `EARLY` pane is retained when the Watermark is reached and the Window is closed which is denoted by `ON_TIME` Pane.

Whereas, in the case of `DISCARDING` pane the values from `EARLY` pane are discarded and the `ON_TIME` pane is empty.

In real world scenarios where the elements stream via Pub/Sub more than 1 EARLY pane can get fired. In a simulated scenario because all the values are already present it cannot trigger more than 1 `EARLY` pane.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! And yeah, the difference in behavior becomes more obvious when using a stream instead of batch